# Windows host terminal to Linux VirtualBox guest

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox, terminal

Given Ubuntu 12.10 running in VirtualBox on a Windows 7 host, is there a way to set up a terminal such that the terminal is running on Windows but connects to Ubuntu by telnet/SSH/whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), it's a client which handles ssh/telnet/whatewer:) and try to connect to your ubuntu ip address with ssh on port 22.

If that won't work install sshd server on ubuntu (in console): `apt-get install openssh-server`

And try putty again.

Comment: Okay I've installed Putty and openssh-server and rebooted the virtual machine, ifconfig says `inet addr:10.0.2.15` and I'm trying to connect to that with SSH on port 22, but the connection times out. What am I missing?

Comment: Check if sshd is running `ps aux | grep ssh`, if it's listening on port 22 `netstat -l -n -p | grep ssh` and if there are some firewall rules `iptables -L -n`.

Comment: It seems sshd is running, there are no firewall rules, and the netstat output contains lines with `0.0.0.0:22` and `:::22` before the word LISTEN, so that all checks out?

Comment: Is ping responding ok?

Comment: No, ping 10.0.2.15 from Windows times out.

Comment: Check your Windows IP, try to ping from linux to windows, which network interface are you using in VirtualBox? (Host, Bridge or NAT)

Comment: Ping from Linux to Windows works fine. VirtualBox network setting is the default, NAT.

Comment: What type of networking are you using on the VB? If you have selected NAT you might have issues. You might have to change the networking mode to bridged so the VB will for all purposes be on your main LAN, thus accessible VIA SSH. If you don't want to do that you will havet to configure port forwarding on the host.

Comment: Or set another Host interface for ssh only.

Comment: I've tried changing it to bridged and rebooting the virtual box and ping from Windows to Linux still times out. There is an associated setting for promiscuous mode which defaults to deny. Might it help if I switch that to allow? Can that be done without compromising security of the host system?

Comment: In bridged mode there'll be different IP address. Are you using new ones?

Comment: Ah, with the new address it works now. Thanks very much!